# How to run multiple projects in one solution in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, multi-project

I am creating a solution that is basically a simple tool to help me with my math. In the main project, there are multiple buttons: Graphing calc., calc., and trigonometry. Each of those are its own separate project. I know how to add them to the solution, but I do not know how to make them run when I click the button for them. Can someone please help me with this? The main project is basically just a main menu for choosing the other projects, but how do I actually open them?

Comment: [`Process.Start()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)?

Comment: What are they, applications? Then a simple [Process.Start()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should do what you want. How is this related to VBA?

Comment: Where would I put process.start though? and exactly what would the code be?

Comment: **1)** You put it at the location in the code where you would like your other apps to start. **2)** The MSDN documentation that I linked you to will explain that for you, or otherwise [the Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+start+an+application+VB.NET).

Comment: Add the code to the Click event handler for the button.